# KHN active filter design

Tags: analog, filter, active-filter, linear

I have some design equations from a text book which are designed to realised a KHN filter. However, when implemented and simulated, the values shown do not realise the design. A gain of 20 dB should be expected in the pass band. I have a feeling it is to do with the large input resistor (R1), and the dividing effect between R1, R2 and R3 meaning the signal is attenuated before even reaching the filter/amplification stage. However, would have assumed this would have been accounted for in design equations.
See page 164, https://gctjaipur.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/continuous-time-active-filter-design.pdf

[image: Circuit_Schematic]

[image: Design Equations]

[image: Frequency Response]

The circuit parameters are seen below:

[image: Table of Parameters]

X is the denominator of equation 4.93c

Comment: The schematic is for a low-pass filter, but the plot is for a high-pass filter.  What aren't you telling us?  Also, the *expected* DC gain of the filter is \$K/\omega_o^2\$, and the gain in the plot -- once it's reached -- is, indeed, about that value.

Comment: @TimWescott SO the circuit has three output simultaneously, this response uploaded happens to be for the High Pass filter part of the response. Also, how have you derived the expected DC gain of the filter? Am I misinterpreting the literature?

Comment: Set \$s = 0\$ in the transfer function -- the result is the DC gain.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Aaaron - are you aware that the original KHN structure has R1 connected to the inverting terminal? Everything else remainc unchanged.

Comment: Perhaps @LvW or jonk might have the time to review the historical changes and reasons for the changes to the schematics published in 1998 by Dilyannis and cited by so many others in oversight and corrected in 1999. So were both versions once used and confused by citations? But Aaron ought to use the 1999 book or better ones which is well defined.

Comment: I know that both versions do exist and can work. The background (and motivation) for my comment was the problem the questioner has described. Perhaps he has used the set of formulas for one version and was surprised that it could not be applied to the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KHN (Kerwin, Huelsman, Newcomb) biquad schematic was quoted ref 1998 has the wrong schematic for your formulae.  It was originally published by KHN in 1968. I used it successfully 10yrs later.  It was written before 1995 yet published in 1998 with the positive feedback input then changed to the inverted version in 1999 by [Deliyannis](https://gctjaipur.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/continuous-time-active-filter-design.pdf) et al yet the older version was requoted  [here](https://aslk-pro.readthedocs.io/de/latest/Experiment_04.html), I believe in error in a great textbook by and then required by too many who failed to recognize the differences to make the BPF output non-inverting.

Fortunately there is some historical analysis done by Soliman on Researchgate in 2008 (TL;DR) [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Am-Soliman/publication/220337734_History_and_Progress_of_the_Kerwin-huelsman-newcomb_Filter_Generation_and_op_Amp_Realizations/links/5ead2702a6fdcc7050a1a7ce/History-and-Progress-of-the-Kerwin-huelsman-newcomb-Filter-Generation-and-op-Amp-Realizations.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=KNKmcWntX7pOUcdU0BFJNYopRl2Eo9lii1xBnUWZBqTPnmE9FhSlK9S5oJOxmq3bqScjWSTTtCfuS1N9lU7n6g.9IuNzoylFoQewd5ZgSK13Qlvtrb3bUz-_JxRU8PMPR9-OXCDi-Hj7Zu2Ia6o8JJzClWQ5vmTPD027tTTYRvatA&_sg%5B1%5D=6TBo_WklWMV9kRdJiqzYboBHcZcYhx-mfQQGl9HTGQp2LjYtyhMHR7JyJZ6Bj9fY5OuXOY5noVMktptzRIZQBlzAZsrHJSxjzMKPhLm7XrmT.9IuNzoylFoQewd5ZgSK13Qlvtrb3bUz-_JxRU8PMPR9-OXCDi-Hj7Zu2Ia6o8JJzClWQ5vmTPD027tTTYRvatA&_iepl=) which may clear up your confusion of formulae and 2 different versions.

From a casual look, you are correct to assume the results are incorrect and the R1/R2 ratio is good for more than 100 dB attenuation.

Try the inverted input version or if you prefer, figure out how citations got screwed up without corrections.

If anyone has corrections to my comments , feel,free to edit if you know better.